# Single machine on network runs Minecraft slowly on internet server, but fine locally

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

So I have a very unusual problem. I have set up a minecraft server for the family to play on. We have four computers. Three of them can connect fine to the server. The fourth one however can not, when it connects it lags out completely, even if it is the only computer using our internet connection (100Mbps Down, 25Mbps Up). It is actually the EXACT same model/spec as one of the other computers, and this other machine does not exhibit the same problem.

This problem computer can run minecraft fine in single player; it can also run minecraft fine when connecting to another machine on our network where I have started a single player game and done 'Open to LAN'. The problem computer can also connect to for example World of Warcraft and have no lag problems.

Server is running vanilla minecraft 1.8.x (I've tried a few different versions, all gave the same problem).
All computers running minecraft 1.8.7 with the appropriate optifine.

I think I've provided all relevant information, if there is anything else I can add please let me know.

Comment: Take a speed test on each computer, post the results, also screenprint/shot this page of your task manager, http://gyazo.com/2e86fd58b43bd17e8ff0e5fcf105f44f (Right click your taskbar and select task manager then click the performance tab) on the troubled computer

Comment: When you say it "lags out" does that mean it freezes up or you have actual server lag, meaning that nobody moves and nothing seems to be happening, but you can move just fine?

Comment: @APCoding The problem computer drops to 0-1fps. If other players are on the server they are completely unaffected.

ModCloud, will see about getting those for you shortly.

Comment: OK, that is called **client lag**. It looks as if the computer is overwhelmed by the information it has to process

Comment: @David Gillen Does it force quit right after connecting to the server? If so, what is the error report it shows?

Comment: @ModCloud Task Manager screenshot when MC running locally http://imgur.com/FIDYbfl and running against speedtest.net showed 14Mbps down, and 10Mbps up. That's with multple other  devices on the network using the broadband connection too.

Comment: @APCoding Doesn't quit immediately. It stays in game until I force quit at 0-1fps only. I've just tried it on the uhc.eximiusgaming.com public server and it's fine there. It appears to be just between this one machine and my server.

Comment: @DavidGillen Okay so this is definitely client lag and from your resource usage I'd say this is actually a problem with the Minecraft executable itself, are all computers using the same types of processor and storage device, a HDD and 64-bit/32-bit processor. I recommend clicking the windows start button and type in the search either %appdata% then click Roaming or C:\Users\"youraccount"\AppData\Roaming (Replace "youraccount" with your computers user without the quotes) then delete the folder .minecraft, save worlds, texturepacks first then re-install Minecraft from http://www.minecraft.net

Comment: @ModCloud The problem machine is absolutely identical to 1 other machine on the network with the exception that the other machine had a second HDD installed for storing large images for processing. MC on the other machine runs from the original HDD, and runs fine. I previously tried a wipe of minecraft from the machine, and last weekend did a complete format and OS reinstall. The minecraft I'm using bar optifine (which I also tried without) is completely fresh. Not evening using my usual Faithful32x32 texture pack. I do appreciate all the suggestions though. :D

Comment: @DavidGillen I'll keep brain racking dude

Comment: @ModCloud - Finally got it sorted.

Comment: @DavidGillen aww brilliant!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So we have a solution (all credit to my better half for figuring this one out). The solution was to go in to Configure Java -> General -> Network Settings and change it from Proxy using the browser settings to Direct Connect. Not sure why it was set that way to begin with, but that sorted it.